# Adding a dimmer switch to a three way switch setup

Tags: electrical, lighting

Once the switch was installed, I ended up with a spare neutral. If I cap the neutral at the dimmer location, the other switch needs to remain in the ON position. Which is fine and everything works as it should. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Are you calling it neutral because it’s white? Or why?  It sounds like you installed a single pole dimmer in the place of a 3-way switch.  It would be better to get the correct 3-way dimmer.

Comment: Neutral is always white but white is not always neutral.   The cable between two 3-way switches needs 3 wires (+ground), and often none of them are neutral.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes? Also, what make and model dimmer did you install?

Comment: A three way has no ON position so to speak. Could you post pictures of your switches?